# mysql driver error - Passing a "string" value to mysql "int" data type column doesn't give an error but saves it as 0

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

- I have a Laravel project using Mysql
- I pass a "string" value to an "int" data column
- It saves as 0
- It does not pass an error while inserting through laravel application
- However it shows an error when I manually try to enter a string to the int column.
- Even in "ENUM - not null" column, it saves as null when a different value is entered. How does it happen?

Comment: This could be the MySQL driver you are using at work.  Perhaps it is trying to marshall your string data as best it can.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions should include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet. Please, read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section to improve your question

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, is there any way to fix it ??? Thanks I'm using mysql driver with Laravel

Comment: Stop inserting strings into numeric columns.  It is _your_ responsibility to control what your Laravel application is doing.